Inconsistent tensor device management detected by autograd
In my code, I encountered issues with tensor device management, specifically with tensors stored in custom containers (TensorPack objects). Initially, tensors were defaulting to CPU, even when the model was moved to GPU. To address this, I manually added functions to ensure tensors were correctly assigned to the same device as the model parameters. However, during backpropagation, device-related issues persisted for tensors within TensorPack objects, impacting gradient computation and model performance, it is my guess and not sure about that.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance in resolving this issue.
Here is a simple code to reproduce the error:
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import torch
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

import torch.nn as nn
from typing import List, Tuple
import numpy as np
import torch.jit as jit
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import Parameter
import torch.optim as optim



########################
# operation's core
########################
class TensorPack(object):
  def __init__(self, tensors:List[torch.Tensor], shapes:List[List[int]]):  
    self.tensors = tensors
    for tensor in self.tensors:tensor.retain_grad()
    
  def to(self, device):
    self.tensors = [tensor.to(device) for tensor in self.tensors]
    return self

    
def TPMatmul(input:torch.Tensor, tensor_pack:TensorPack):
  # keep it very simple : Input * Tensor1 * Tensor2 * ...
  mode = len(tensor_pack.tensors)
  data = input
  for i in range(mode):
    data = torch.matmul(data, tensor_pack.tensors[i])
  return data
  
  
########################
# Layer's main operation
########################
class operation(jit.ScriptModule):
  def __init__(self, in_features:int, out_features:int, mode:int):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.in_features = in_features
    self.out_features = out_features
    self.kernel_size = in_features * out_features
    self.mode = mode
    self.shapes = np.zeros((mode,2)).astype('int32')
    self.div = int(self.out_features//self.mode)
    self.shapes[0] = (in_features, self.div)
    self.inds = np.zeros(self.mode+1).astype('int32')
    self.inds[1] = np.prod(self.shapes[0])
    for i in range(1, self.mode):
      dim1 = (i) * self.div
      dim2 = (i+1) * self.div
      if i == self.mode - 1:dim2 = self.out_features 
      self.shapes[i]=(dim1, dim2)
      self.inds[i+1] = self.inds[i] + dim1 * dim2
    self.kernel_length = np.sum(np.prod(self.shapes, axis=1))
    self.shapes = self.shapes.tolist()
    self.kernels = Parameter(torch.rand((self.kernel_length,)))
    self.construct_tensor_pack()
    

  @torch.jit.export
  def construct_tensor_pack(self):
    tensors = torch.jit.annotate(List[Tensor], [])
    for i in range(self.mode):
      dim1 = self.shapes[i][0]
      dim2   = self.shapes[i][1]
      kernel = torch.reshape(self.kernels[self.inds[i]:self.inds[i+1]],(dim1, dim2))
      kernel.retain_grad()
      tensors.append(kernel)
      
    # construct a simple container
    self.tensor_pack = TensorPack(tensors, self.shapes)
    
  @torch.jit.export
  def forward(self, input: Tensor):
    return TPMatmul(input, self.tensor_pack)
    
  def to(self, device):
    super().to(device)
    self.tensor_pack = self.tensor_pack.to(device)
    return self


    
##########
# Layer
##########
class Layer(jit.ScriptModule):
  def __init__(self, in_features:int, out_features:int, mode:int):
    super(Layer, self).__init__()  
    self.op = operation(in_features, out_features, mode)
    
  @jit.script_method
  def forward(self, inputs: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    inputs_ts = inputs.unbind(1)
    outputs = torch.jit.annotate(List[Tensor], [])
    for i in range(len(inputs_ts)):
      out = self.op(inputs_ts[i])
      outputs += [out]
    outputs = torch.stack(outputs, dim=1)
    return outputs

  def to(self, device):
    super().to(device)
    self.op.to(device)
    return self


##########
# Model
##########
class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_features:int = 16 , out_features:int = 48, mode:int = 3):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    self.in_features = in_features
    self.out_features = out_features
    self.mode = mode
    self.layer = Layer(self.in_features, self.out_features, self.mode)
    self.act = nn.Sigmoid()
  def forward(self, x):
    y = self.layer(x)
    z = self.act(y)
    return z

  def to(self, device):
    super().to(device)
    self.layer = self.layer.to(device)
    return self


model = Model()
device = torch.device("cuda")
model.to(device)
print("")
print("==================================")
print(f"Model device set to: {device}")
print(f"kernels.device:{model.layer.op.kernels.device}")
for i in range(model.mode):
  print(f"tensor_pack.tensors[{i}].device:{model.layer.op.tensor_pack.tensors[i].device}")
print("==================================")

batch_size  = 8 
seq_length  = 28
in_features = 16
out_features = 48
model = Model()
device = torch.device("cuda")
model.to(device)
model.train()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.005)
inputs  = torch.rand((batch_size, seq_length, in_features)).to(device)
targets = torch.rand((batch_size, seq_length, out_features)).to(device)
import torch
with torch.autograd.detect_anomaly(True):
  outputs = model(inputs)
  criterion = nn.BCELoss()
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
  print("")
  print(f"inputs.device:{inputs.device}")
  print(f"outputs.device:{outputs.device}")
  print(f"targets.device:{targets.device}")
  print(f"loss.device:{loss.device}")
  print("")
  print("==================================")
  loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  optimizer.step()



